# MySQLDump not working to import data into amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have done some data processing elsewhere and want to reimport a few tables...i already exported data from that db through the mysqldump function. I tried to reimport into my RDS yet no luck...

I used the following command to try to reimport

mysqldump --host=blink10.cfti81qgpnos.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com --password=XXXXXXX --user=bill --single-transaction blink10 products productspriceNEW < /data/tt.sql

It seemed to run through all the data in putty and left me with:

- Dump completed on 2012-01-31  9:27:55

However when I check the database, none of these records are added. Thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

The best way to import a large (30GB+) mysql database to RDS is the following:

`mysql --max_allowed_packet=256M -h [end point url] -u [master username] -p`

Once logged in:

```
use [your database name];
select now(); source /path/to/yourSqlFile.sql; select now();
```

`select now();` to find out the time it took to import the file if needed;

Answer (score 3):

mysqldump is for copying data *from* a MySQL database to a file.  It is not for importing data back into a database.

I think what you want to do might be as simple as:

```
mysql --host=blink10.cfti81qgpnos.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com \
  --password=XXXXXXX --user=bill < /data/tt.sql
```

but this depends a bit on what tt.sql contains.

Be very careful when performing this as you could be overwriting data you care about if everything isn't aligned correctly.

Comment: tt.sql only has 2 tables which are in blink10 database...ideally i would like reimport these to the RDS, i enter [root@domU-12-31-39-0A-61-AC /]# mysql --host=blink10.cfti81qgpnos.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com --password=XXXX --user=bill blink10 products productspriceNEW < /data/tt.sql and it just shows me the mysql help file

Comment: Make sure the file you are reading into the mysql command only has the tables you want to import and is named with the names you want to create.  Specifying extra table names on the command line has no effect except to have mysql tell you you are running it incorrectly.